# Extract value from xml tag in SOAP response payload

Tags: php, xml, soap

I´m trying to extract the RecordID = "1014276" from a tag

I tried with :

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml2 = simplexml_load_string($result);
echo $latitude = (string) $xml2['RecordID'];
```

This is the XML response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns1:createDataResponse xmlns:ns1="http://3e.pl/ADInterface">
         <StandardResponse RecordID="1014276" xmlns="http://3e.pl/ADInterface"/>
      </ns1:createDataResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This involves a bit more than just accessing the attribute, first you have to select the correct element.  Using XPath is the most comment way in this sort of structure. 
 As this has a default namespace defined for the data, you will need to register this with the SimpleXMLElement first (using `$xml2->registerXPathNamespace("ns1","http://3e.pl/ADInterface");`.

You can then find the element using the XPAth expression `//ns1:StandardResponse`.  As the `xpath()` method returns a list of found elements, use `[0]` to just extract the first match.  You should then be able to extract the attribute as in your code using the resultant element...

```
$xml2 = simplexml_load_string($result);
$xml2->registerXPathNamespace("ns1","http://3e.pl/ADInterface");

$response = $xml2->xpath("//ns1:StandardResponse")[0];
echo (string) $response['RecordID'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apporach this as

```
$xml = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soap:Body>
  <ns1:createDataResponse xmlns:ns1="http://3e.pl/ADInterface">
     <StandardResponse RecordID="1014276" xmlns="http://3e.pl/ADInterface"/>
  </ns1:createDataResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xml, $values, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);

echo $values[3]['attributes']['RECORDID'];
```

Comment: I used this way to get the value between <DATA> tag
<RunProcessResponse IsReport="true" xmlns="ADInterface">
<Data>3C68</Data>
</RunProcessResponse>